# Absolute position inside relative position, element goes over parent's width?

Tags: html, css

Kindly refer to the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ukzKT/8/.

I want the inner div #this-bottom to stay at bottom, but it's width should be like any other div inside it. ie it should stay inside the padding area of the parent div #top.

**CSS**

```
#top{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #222;
}
#this-bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid #333;
    right: 18px;
    left: 20px;
}
#other{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #333;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='top'>
    <div id='other'>
        This is 1 <br />
        THis is 2 <br />
        This is 3 <br />

    </div>
    <div id='this-bottom'>
        This should be bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you expect this behaviour when you have no CSS defined?

Comment: @Diodeus sorry (wrong fiddle). check now.

Comment: @ShahalTharique there no issue with your css it's normal that it goes over parent width, becasue you are using `padding:20;`

Comment: @mgraph yeah, i know.. any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the div goes outside of the parent is there is a `width` of `100%` and `left` is being assigned the default value ('auto') - which in this case is `20px` due to the `padding`. So the `div` will flow `20px` outside of the parent container.

To stop this from happening, you can set `left: 20px` and `right: 20px` (same as padding) and remove `width: 100%`

Comment: actually it's not a guess;) As long as you don't define any of the 4 directions, the elements original values are taken.